# zend framework: can not access file that is already there

Tags: php, zend-framework, file-io

I am trying to read and post back to the browser a file uploaded with the zend framework mechanism.

The file has been uploaded correctly to the desired location and as I have checked by

```
su www-data
```

and after an ls and a cat, the web user can read it and modify it properly.

the problem is that inside a controller when I try to:

```
if(!file_exists($fileName)) {
die("File ($fileName) wasnt set or it didnt exist");
}
```

I am always getting to die(...), although the $fileName is a string and when I display it's location I can always (as stated before) read it from the command line.

ls output:

```
$ ls -lah
total 112K
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4.0K 2009-10-07 18:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data 4.0K 2009-10-07 13:57 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  70K 2009-10-07 17:33 Eclipse_Icon_by_TZR_observer.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  27K 2009-10-07 18:24 eclipse_logo2.png
```

Stat output:

```
stat() [function.stat]: stat failed for .../eclipse_logo2.png
```

I saw a very similar question to the "try for 30 days" site, so it is not something that has happened to me...

Any ideas?

Comment: 1. can you post the ls -l file.ext output or stat($fileName)?
2. can you post the similar question to the "try for 30 days"

Comment: definitely: added that to the question body

Comment: For the second question: No it is a "register first forum" and I really do not want to register there...

Comment: Hummm seems to be the safe mode error check http://www.php.net/file_exists also please try stat($fileName); and put the output of die, maybe is a path error... PS: about the "register first forum" try with Google cached version ;)

Comment: $fileName appears to contain a relative path - where is the PHP script relative to the file location? Also try: echo realpath($fileName); and see if that looks right.

Comment: also you can get the current working directory with getcwd();

Comment: I did an attemt: I moved the file to /var/www/ folder and wrote something like
$fileName = '/var/www/logo2.png'; and it worked!
So there must be something in the "chain" of directories down to the file...

Comment: and also to Tim fountain: the file is in an absolute path, I ommitde the full path to make the question more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to [chmod](http://php.net/chmod) the newly created file because the file owner created from PHP side will be Apache (group: www-data, httpd, www, or something similar). So next time PHP cannot access the file because www-data owns it and it has wrong permissions.

```
Here's how you create new files so that you can access them later.
<?php
$path = '/path/to/new/file';
touch($path)
chmod($path, 0777);
// TRY to change group, this usually fails
@chgrp($path, filegroup(__FILE__)); 
// TRY to change owner, this usually fails
@chown($path, fileowner(__FILE__));
```

Comment: Thanks it is obvious that this is a permissions issue, I will try it and will inform ASAP...

Comment: Considered as correct, because there was as well a permissions issue.
What was the real problem after that:
I had forgotten to trim the result from the postgresql, having as input not only the filename but a large number of trailing spaces as well. The real-fix therefore was a trim(...) call.